# renderRow index from each row in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, scripting

I am trying to get the current index of renderRow but I dont seem to get it. I have also tried to add i in as a variable inside renderRow. I am making highscore and it would be super convenient if I could just get the number from renderRow itself. If there is another way to get the current number each time then it will also work.

```
          <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData, rowID ) =>
          <Text style={styles.topStyle}>{rowID}</Text>
          }
      />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `renderRow` callback expects a function with 4 arguments `renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID, higlightRow) => { ... }}`. I believe `rowId` is the one you need.

The docs — http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow

Comment: Also a common pattern is to use an `_` for ignored parameters although i'm not a fan of it because e.g. the lodash library uses the same. They should just change that and pass an object so that the caller can deconstruct it.

Comment: Hi, thanks but how can you make it start from 1 at least this {rowID + 1} didn't work.

Comment: I believe `rowId` is just a numerical identifier of the row, it is not intended to start from 1. Alternatively you can just keep you own `index` variable — init it to `0` in the beginning of the `render` and then use it like `index++`.